# Not getting styles while generating pdf from html

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, pdfkit, html-to-text

I am using pdfKit and html-to-text for generating pdfs from html. The problem currently is, styles from html are not reflecting in pdf. I am open for both type of solutions, if problem can be solved with these packages or we have to change.

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const {convert} =require('html-to-text');
const {PassThrough}=require("stream");
const generateCombinedCertificatePDFBuff = (context, compiledHTML) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const doc = new PDFDocument();
      const buffer = [];
      const stream = new PassThrough();

      doc.pipe(stream);
      doc.text(convert(compiledHTML));
      doc.end();

      stream.on("data", (chunk) => buffer.push(chunk));
      stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buffer)));
      stream.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Note: I am shifting from puppeteer (due to the huge time it is taking), i have also tried html-pdf (having some styling issues in it too), don't recommend these.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the html you are trying to convert?